Nonlinear Markovian feedback in quantum mechanics?
A quantum system monitored by a sequence of weak measurements obeys a stochastic equation of the form (taken from Eq.(30) of Ref. [1]):
$$ \textrm{d}|\psi_t\rangle = \{ -(i/\hbar) H \textrm{d}t -k(X-\langle X\rangle)^2 \textrm{d}t +\sqrt{2k}(X-\langle X\rangle)\textrm{d}W \}|\psi_t\rangle,$$
where $H$ is the system's Hamiltonian, $X$ is the observable that is monitored with strength $k$ and $\textrm{d}W$ is the infinitesimal Wiener increment. This can be obtained by weak measurements made at regular intervals $\Delta t$ which become less and less precise as $\Delta t$ decreases. To this dynamics one can also associate the "measurement current" $I(t)$ such that (using a mixture of notations between [1] and [2]) $I(t)\textrm{d}t = \langle X\rangle \textrm{d}t + (8k)^{-1/2}\textrm{d}W$.
It is said on page 3, left column, around Eq.(2.10) of [2], that in this case the only possible Markovian feedback is given by $H_{\rm fb} (t) = F(t)I(t)$, where $F(t)$ is an Hermitian operator because "the current is singular and of indefinite sign". In other words, the feedback is linear in the measurement results. In Ref. [3], page 9, above Eq. (28) a similar point is made. In general, I searched for "Nonlinear Markovian Feedback" and found nothing.
I do not understand why a nonlinear feedback is not possible. Going back to the non-continuous case, nothing prevents someone to make a weak measurement every $\Delta t$ and react with a feedback that depends arbitrarily on the measurement result. For example, why it is not possible to have a feedback such as $H_{\rm fb} (t) = F(t)I^2(t)$ or $H_{\rm fb} (t) = F(t)I^3(t)$?
Both mathematical and intuitive explanations are welcome.
Thank you in advance for your help.
[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611067
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201145
[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19748

I will try to give both a mathematical explanation and a more physical argument.
The purely mathematical explanation is just a repetition of what is quoted from Ref. [2] in the OP. Defining $\xi(t) = dW/dt$, the measured current is
$$I(t) = \langle X(t)\rangle + (8k)^{-1/2}\xi(t),$$
where I'm adopting conventions from the OP. This is a highly singular object due to the white-noise contribution $\xi(t)$, which obeys
$$ \langle \xi(t)\rangle = 0,\quad \langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = \delta(t-t').$$
As such, it becomes clear that higher powers of the current such as $I(t)^2$ etc. are not well defined. In particular, the average $\langle I(t)^2\rangle$ contains a factor proportional to $\langle \xi(t)^2\rangle = \delta(0)$, which is obviously divergent.
Of course, in a real experiment the measurement record one obtains is not singular. The current is sampled at some finite rate, and the results are recorded by electronic circuits whose response time is non-zero. So the actual measurement record is related to the idealised measurement current $I(t)$ by a low-pass filter. Assuming that this filtering is dominated by the finite sampling rate, in each time step $\Delta t$ one obtains a measurement outcome
$$ \Delta I(t) = \langle X(t)\rangle \Delta t + (8k)^{-1/2}\Delta W_t,$$
where $\Delta W_t$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and variance $\Delta t$, and I'm assuming that $\Delta t$ is so small that $\langle X(t)\rangle $ can be treated as constant within each timestep. There is no singularity here: the measurement record is ultimately just a list of real numbers stored in memory.
Now, one can certainly apply feedback using this record however one likes, e.g. by applying a unitary $U_{\rm fb}(t) = e^{-i F(t)\Delta I(t)^2}$. Assuming this unitary can be applied instantaneously and that the measurement is efficient, this would lead to the evolution over one time step
$$ \rho(t+\Delta t) = U_{\rm fb}(t)[\rho(t+\Delta t)]_0U_{\rm fb}^\dagger(t),$$
where $[\rho(t+\Delta t)]_0 = \rho(t) + [\Delta \rho(t)]_0$ is the (stochastic, measurement-conditioned) evolution in the absence of feedback. Since $\Delta t$ is small, we can Taylor expand:
\begin{align}
\rho(t+\Delta t) & = \rho(t) + [\Delta \rho(t)]_0 -i \Delta I(t)^2[F(t),\rho(t)] + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)\\ 
& = \rho(t)+ [\Delta \rho(t)]_0 -i \left( 2\langle X(t)\rangle \Delta W_t\Delta t  + \frac{\Delta W_t^2}{8k}\right) [F(t),\rho(t)] + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^{2}).
\end{align}
Therefore, up to corrections of order $\mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)$, we have succeeded only in feeding random noise back into the system. Indeed, the term proportional to $\Delta W_t$ will have vanishing effect on average, so the main contribution at linear order in $\Delta t$ (the same order as $[\Delta \rho]_0$) is the $\Delta W_t^2$ term. On average, this will simply add a deterministic (state-independent) shift to the Hamiltonian, which we could implement much more easily without any feedback.
Of course, one could also consider larger values of $\Delta t$, so that higher order terms are not negligible. But now, we can no longer approximate $\langle X(t)\rangle$ as constant within each time step, so that the measurement record becomes
$$\Delta I(t) = \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t} dt' \langle X(t')\rangle + (8k)^{-1/2}\Delta W_t.$$
Obviously, now the measurement record at time $t+\Delta t$ depends on the history of the state over the timestep, so feeding it back directly into the system will anyway lead to non-Markovian dynamics.
To sum up: linear feedback is the only form of direct feedback that produces a significant effect (compared to the effect of noise that is also unavoidably fed back), assuming that one is working in the Markovian limit where measurement results depend only on the instantaneous state. Nonlinear feedback can be implemented by dropping the latter assumption. One way to describe this systematically has been reported recently by Annby-Andersson et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 129, 050401 (2022).

Hi, thank you for the help and the reference! I think I am ok with the mathematical argument. I can generalize it like follows.
Given any continuous function $f(I)$, I can say that it can be approximated like $f(I(t))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k I^k$ because of Weierstrass approximation theorem.
The part with $k=0$ does not have dynamical consequences while for any $k \geq 2$ one gets divergences. So I have to stay with just the linear term.

Regarding the more physical argument, I still need to think better about it. What you call outcome seems to be $\Delta I/\Delta t$ in Ref.[1] [page 5, Eq. (26)], so maybe the exponential to apply should be $U_{\rm fb} (t,\Delta t) = \exp { -i F(t)[\Delta I/\Delta t]^k \Delta t }$ instead of $U_{\rm fb} (t,\Delta t) = \exp { -i F(t)[\Delta I]^k }$.

In the first comment I had to write "The part with $k=0$ just gives a state-independent feedback" instead of "The part with $k=0$ does not have dynamical consequences".

Hi @Knomes regarding the second comment – I see no difference between what you and I wrote because $F(t)$ is completely arbitrary. I can just define $F(t) = F'(t)/(\Delta t)^{k-1}$. Or in other words the "measurement record" is only uniquely defined up to an arbitrary overall factor, which is why one sees many different conventions in the literature without inconsistency.

Reference [2] seems to be require linearity because they want the resulting reduced system dynamics to be Markovian, rather than the system as a whole, mentioned in footnote [35]. In other words, it feels like they choose to have a linear system, than for it to be a requirement of the setup.
It also stood out the fact that the resulting feedback mechanism is $F(t) \times I(t)$ and not $F(t)I(t)$. If this refers to a cross product due to the way we can have a system be impacted by the current, i.e. by the magnetic/electric fields, it might explain why the shape $F(t) \times I(t)$ is required. I have not pursued this line of thought thoroughly.
I hope this helps!

Hi, thank you for trying to help.  Sadly, I don't think you have answered my question. Let me go into more details.

When I write about Markovian dynamics I use the term "Markovian" in the same sense of Ref [2], i.e., the state of the system at time $t+\textrm{d}t$ only depends on the state of the system at time $t$. Since we are deriving the stochastic equation by means of (somewhat idealized) measurements and feedback, we are not concerned with the dynamics of the system performing the measurements and the feedback. So we avoid saying "reduced".

I continue in the next comment



Both in [2] and [3] it seems to me they clearly say that a Markovian dynamics only allows a linear feedback.


$I(t)$ is a scalar quantity. I do not know why they write $F(t)\times I(t)$ instead of $F(t)I(t)$. You can see in Eq.(28) of [3], which is given in a more general form with multiple measurement and feedback mechanisms, that there is no cross-product.


